# Rspec: when the matcher fails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I have a Rails project and use RSpec as a testing framework. What I need is to subscribe to the event when some matcher fails, e.g. I got this:

```
true.should be_false
```

I want to do some action on every fail. Is this functionality provided by the RSpec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the hooks, not certain it will help but where it passes example in to the block (in the docs) you may be able to get the result...

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks

Comment: Thanks, used the around hook which was just what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can monkey-patch this behavior into RSpec::Core::Example class:

```
require 'spec_helper'
class RSpec::Core::Example  
  def failed?
    !@exception.nil?
  end
end

describe "my_tested_things" do 
 ...
end
```

Then you can ensure it will run your desired code after all failing matches:

```
after(:each) do    
  run_my_code if example.failed?    
end
```